# Equivalent to Source Maps or Providing Source Location Hints to Compiler

Tags: luatex, pandoc, debugging

I'm using Pandoc and LuaLaTeX and have organized my project into several dozen LaTeX embedded Markdown documents into a final output document. Effectively, each chapter is a document and combined with a LaTeX preamble and bibtex bibliography.

For my workflow, this is a pretty optimal setup, however, Pandoc generates a single `.tex` file which is then compiled by `lualatex`. When errors occur, they point to this monolithic tex file which bears little resemblance to the source input.

Does LuaLaTeX (or any TeX) support the equivalent of a [`LineEntry`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/structllvm_1_1gsym_1_1LineEntry.html), [source map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map), Java's [`SourceFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.10) and [`LineNumberTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.12) attributes, or other debug symbol that could be emitted to identify the origin file and line in the final document?

Obviously Pandoc would need to emit that data, I'm mostly wondering if the concept exists in the TeX world.

Comment: Pandoc lets you include a wide range of "raw" LaTeX control sequences in your Markdown source, so you could insert a line something like `\typeout{File A starts here}` at the top of each of your Markdown source files. These would get written to the log file produced by LuaLaTeX which might help you pin down the errors (which would also be in the log).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE by the way!

Comment: Yes, **obviously pandoc would need to emit the data**. Then what's your problem? If there's the data you can just look at the line of error in the TeX file, query it against the map to get the error in the md file. Not automatically, however.

Comment: Sometimes talking (typing) through a problem is really all that’s necessary. Thanks for the `\typeout` suggestion, that should work perfectly. After looking at my `Makefile` and the pandoc options, I don’t see a reason I need a monolithic output document in the first place and incrementally converting the individual files has benefits beyond easier debugging.